# Populate one input field based on other

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `angular.js` in my project. In the template I have :

```
 <div class='form-group'>
   <label>Field 1</label>
  <input type='text' ng-model='f1' required class="form-control">
 </div>


 <div class='form-group'>
    <label>Field 2</label>
     <input type='text' ng-model='f1' required class="form-control">
 </div>
```

My `controller` right now is using only one model `$scope.f1`

I want to pre-populate `Field 2` based on `Field 1`. But since I am using the same model
if I write something in `Field 2` overwrites `Field 1`.

I don't want this behavior. I should be able to edit `Field 2` later without affecting `Field 1`.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope), it registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.f1;
},
function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.f2 = $scope.f1;
}, true);
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5zqkj7iYloeHYkzK1Prt?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: elegant! but need to note that your second field is binded to another variable (`f2`)

Comment: @Cherniv, see the demo I hope that will handle your concern

Comment: @Satpal . Thanks a lot. $watch handles all my concern ,almost. I am playing with the code there. Thanks for posting the demo,very helpful :)