# angularjs one-way-data-binding, can angular do it?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple question about angularjs one-way-data-binding.

Assume that in same page, we have two input box **A** and **B**,

How can they work like:

input **A** will change input **B**, but input **B** will NOT change input **A**,

I know angular has bindonce, but I want is one-way-data-binding

thanks for your answer..... I tried, but all solutions are failed.........:(

Can we add something like directive to controll it?

Comment: You can put a watcher on input A's variable and make it set input B's variable whenever it is changed.

Comment: Try something before asking questions, If you already have, then add your code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate one input field based on other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266566/populate-one-input-field-based-on-other)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `ng-value`. It will show the model, but not update it. Doesn't require any extra JS wiring.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a">
<input type="text" ng-value="a">
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nnKEpWbFDa6tQAFc5M0f)

Comment: Epic solution. Completely forgot about this directive.

Comment: can we use something like directive

Comment: @Awakening Not sure what you mean. `ng-model` and `ng-value` are directives.

Comment: how use `ng-change` with `ng-value`?

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dmcyAmO0bQO6OVwFVq4c?p=preview)

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a">
<input type="text" ng-model="b">
```

JS

```
// Put this code in your controller
$scope.$watch('a', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ($scope.b === undefined || newValue !== oldValue) {
        $scope.b = newValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we use something like directive ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a" data-ng-change="valueChange(a)">
<input type="text" ng-model="b">
```

Js:

```
$scope.valueChange=function(newValue){
     $scope.b = newValue;    
}
```

Comment: Can we use something like directive?